# Accessing files made with mktemp for Linux through C++

Tags: c++, linux

I am trying to create a temporary file on a Linux system, but interfacing through C++ (so that the Linux commands are run through the C++ program).

To do so, I am using mktemp, which produces a temporary file. 
I would need to later refer back to this file.
However, the filename is randomly generated and I am wondering if there is an easy way to access the filename.

Comment: Are you talking about the `mktemp(1)` command or the `mktemp(3)` library function?

Comment: The `mktemp(3)` function has been removed from POSIX, you should use one of the `mkstemp` family of functions. See http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mkstemp.3.html

Comment: The `mktemp` command prints the name of the file it created. You can pass it as an argument to the program: `yourprogram $(mktemp)`

Comment: You never state the problem. What, exactly, is the problem? Also, please show some of your code around the problem area.

Comment: in other words do **not** use 'system("mktemp");' use a library call to a `mkstemp()` variant. What is your reason for needing a temp file?

Answer (score 2):

The big honking comment in `mktemp(3)`'s manual page explicitly tells you to use `mkstemp(3)` instead of `mktemp(3)`, and explains the good reason why it is so.

If you actually [read the manual page for `mkstemp(3)`](http://manpages.courier-mta.org/htmlman3/mkstemp.3.html) it clearly explains that the library function modifies the character buffer that's passed to it as a parameter to reflect the actual name of the created temporary file.

So to determine the name of the temporary file, simply refer to the character buffer you passed to this library function.